# Getting the file size from StreamWriter

Tags: c#, streamwriter

```
using (var writer = File.CreateText(fullFilePath))
{
   file.Write(fileContent);
}
```

Given the above code, can the file size be known from `StreamWriter`?

Comment: Yes; it's empty.

Comment: Sorry. I got the following as well. `writer.Write(fileContent);`

Comment: Code looks too much simplified. You will get answers about getting the size _after_ the using closes it, is that what you want?

Comment: yes. from the streamwriter class if possible.

Comment: You can't get the size from a _closed_ writer or stream.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, you can, try the following

```
long length = writer.BaseStream.Length;//will give unexpected output if autoflush is false and write has been called just before
```

Note: `writer.BaseStream.Length` property can return unexpected results since `StreamWriter` doesn't write immediately. It caches so to get expected output you need `AutoFlush = true`

```
writer.AutoFlush = true; or writer.Flush();
long length = writer.BaseStream.Length;//will give expected output
```

Comment: @Downvoter care to explain

Comment: Setting AutoFlush after a write works but it is silly. Just call `Flush()` when appropriate.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you are looking for if you need properties of a specific file is FileInfo.

```
FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fullFilePath);
//Gets the size, in bytes, of the current file.
long size = info.Length;
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go! Just use the FileInfo class in the System.IO namespace :)

```
using System.IO;

var fullFilePath = "C:\path\to\some\file.txt";
var fileInfo = new FileInfo(fullFilePath);

Console.WriteLine("The size of the file is: " + fileInfo.Length);
```

Comment: basically correct but better show in context with the `using(){}`

Comment: That is not needed. It has nothing to do with the instantiation of the StreamWriter class. It is only (naturally) required that this is done within the scope of where fullFilePath is defined and declared.

Whether or not the file size is checked before or after writing the content is up to the original poster to decide. But he or she should be perfectly capable of utilizing this code no matter what they intend to do :)

Comment: FileInfo doesn't implement IDisposable therefore a using statement cant be used on it.

Comment: What is the relevance @Bearcat9425? Just instantiate FileInfo after or before writing your file, depending on the behaviour you want, and then set the object to null once you're done. The GC will take care of the rest.

Comment: To the person above stating to show it in context with the using.

Comment: It's relevant to place this outside and after the `using(writer)`.

Comment: The OP should be able to figure that out.

Comment: FileInfo caches, so @HenkHolterman is correct that it must be after the writer completes. Or you need to call Refresh()

Comment: _The OP should be able to figure that out_ - maybe, it still makes it only a half-answer.

Comment: I just tested this. The above code return 0. I have to put `writer.AutoFlush = true;` before creating FileInfo object. I tested this within using block.

Comment: @mohmohoo You have to actually write the data to the file in the file system before the file size increases. That's IO.

Comment: @mohmohoo - inside the using the BaseStream approach is probably faster. The need to call `Flush()` remains.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this piece of code ?

```
var size = writer.BaseStream.Length;
```

*writer is your StreamWriter

Comment: You're not taking the buffering into account.

Answer (score 0):

No, not from StreamWriter itself can you find out about the file's size.  You have to use [FileInfo's Length](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.length.aspx).