# How to ensure that StreamReader.BaseStream.Length will return the correct value?

Tags: c#, streamreader, content-length

I have a loop which compares the `BaseStream.Length` with the `lastMaxOffset` and let's say that 9 out of 10 times runs properly.

But it's this 1 time that BaseStream.Length somehow sets equal to 0 - in debug mode it shows normal value, always greater than 0 - and this causes an issue to my console app.
I verified that the length is NOT equal to 0 since it's a logfile which ONLY grows. So I guess this is a BaseStream issue (maybe temporarily hasn't the length value, so it sets it to 0)
Is there a way to ensure that `StreamReader.BaseStream.Length` will return ONLY the correct value?

```
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(
    new FileStream(path, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.ReadWrite), 
    Encoding.Default))
{
    long lastMaxOffset = this.getMaxOffsetForFile(path);
    if ( lastMaxOffset == 0 )
    {
        lastMaxOffset = this.setMaxOffsetForFile(path, reader.BaseStream.Length);
    }

    reader.DiscardBufferedData();
    long fileLength = reader.BaseStream.Length;

    if (fileLength > lastMaxOffset)
    { 
         //my code 
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18127502/getting-the-file-size-from-streamwriter

Comment: @CodeCaster I already saw this post, and I actually added on my code reader.DiscardBufferedData(); since flush is for StreamWriter, but the error still occurs.

Comment: Then fix the `StreamWriter` in your question. Anyway, the reader buffers as well.

Comment: I think that the `StreamReader.BaseStream` property is a design mistake in the framework. This should not be exposed at all.

Comment: @usr Can you suggest a way to somehow ensure that I will get the correct value? As I said, It's quite rare not to run properly, but I should exclude this possible error

Comment: Need more code, ideally a complete executable piece of code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are reading a file that's actively being written to by another process.  FileShare.ReadWrite gave you the backdoor to do this.  That process has no obligation to make your life easy.

You are using FileStream.Length, there isn't anything wrong with it.  It doesn't do anything but ask the operating system for the file size with GetFileSize().  You can always assume some kind of buggy network file system but that doesn't ever get you anywhere.  The proper assumption to make here is that you *actually* see what this process does.

Once in a while it truncates the file.  You'll get 0 when that happens.  Or some other small number, it doesn't have to be 0 and it certainly doesn't have to repeat when you debug while the process continues to write to the file.

Nothing very unusual for log files, they can't grow forever.  You'll have to write your code to accommodate for this.  Very hard to do 100% correctly, you cannot depend on a reliable Length value.  Only reasonable thing you can do when you get a new value that's less than the previous one is to assume the process started to rewrite the log file so you'll have to start reading again offset 0 (not Length and not lastMaxOffset).  Using a telephone to talk to the programmer of this app to verify these assumptions is highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I already have an if else which is checking if (fileLength < lastMaxOffset) and reads again the whole file. My problem though, is that during my testing, I only add lines in the logfile, so the lastMaxOffset and the fileLength are increasing. But for an unknown reason, at some point, the fileLength is equal to 0 and instead of printing ONLY the new lines, prints again the whole logfile :/

Comment: Hmm, no, this is an answer, not a comment.  It explains why getting 0 is normal.  That this can have unpleasant side-effects on your code, like not properly flushing your own buffered log data, is a given.  Your snippet isn't nearly sufficient to diagnose the reason.  If you don't want to use a telephone then the next best thing to do is write your own test app that logs like this, intentionally truncating the file on command with FileStream.SetLength() to trigger the problem scenario.

Comment: Ok now I got what you meant...! This was helpful. I added a check on the file creation date and now the error doesn't occur. Thanks again for your help

Comment: For a future reference, I've noticed that the error isn't appearing also when I pause the program even for a small amount of time. I added the following line System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(20); and the error hasn't occurred again.