# Limit size of uploaded file in C# REST API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, upload, mime-types, asp.net-core-2.2

I have this code to upload an image file in my c# restful api :

```
using(Streamer reader = new StreamerReader(req.Bindfile().Result.OpenReadStream())) {
    request.Data.Image = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(reader.ReadToEnd());
}
```

I know I am slurping the file in one shot, but I would like to know the "right way" to modify this code so it rejects a file when it is bigger than 10 Megabytes.

I am inspecting the methods of reader instance and I cannot find anything useful other than read the file by blocks and just keep track of how many bytes I have read until that point.

Is that correct? Can someone help me to do this the C# way?

Comment: Is this ASP.net?  And if so, have you considered limiting the upload size in the web.config file [as shown here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/288675/1563833)?

Comment: I do not have that file in my config. Its a RESTful API in .Net Core 2.2

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase upload file size in Asp.Net core](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38698350/increase-upload-file-size-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the amount of bytes present in the stream and convert them to MB like so: amountOfBytes / (1024 * 1024f). You can then check if the amount is above your threshold, in your case 10, and take action accordingly.

Comment: something like this using FileInfo?

 FileInfo info = new FileInfo(fullFilePath);
//Gets the size, in bytes, of the current file.
long size = info.Length;

https://stackoverflow.com/a/18127628/3163418